# Is this proof of the limit $\lim_{x \to 2}(x^2 - 6x) = -8$ legitimate?

Tags: calculus

I am presented with the following task:

Use the formal definition of the limit to prove the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 2}(x^2 - 6x) = -8$$

The way I solved it is very different from the solution presented by the answer-sheet to the exam, thus I am wondering if my proof is legitimate:

Let $|x - 2| < \delta$. From simplicity, bound delta so that $\delta < 1$. Thus we have that $|x-2| < 1$. Now, let $|x^2 - 6x + 8| < \epsilon$. Thus we have that $|x-2||x-4| < \epsilon$. We already have that $|x-2| < 1$, which implies $|x - 2 - 2| < 1 + 2$ (please tell me if my absolute-value logic is off), therefore $|x-4|<3$. This implies $|x-2||x-4|<\epsilon<3\delta$, there an appropiate value for $\delta$ would be $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Comment: Your steps seem fine. However, depending on the teacher, this might be considered an incomplete proof because the proof "begins" when you state $|x-2|<\delta = \epsilon/3$.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $$\delta = min \lbrace 1, \frac{\epsilon}{3} \rbrace?$$

Comment: When you say Let $|x-2|<\delta$ what do you mean? Your post is ambiguous.

Comment: @Zhoe, yes it should.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement involving the absolute value is fine. I don't see why you said $\epsilon$ is less than $3 \delta$. The point behind the proof is, given an arbitrary $\epsilon$, to produce a number $\delta$ satisfying the required condition. In your argument above you started out with $\delta$ (What is that?) and only at the end did you say that $\delta$ should be $\epsilon / 3$. While your work is a good way of finding $\delta$, the heart of the proof is to show that your value of $\delta$ works. In a sense, your work above is scratch work. A complete proof would go something like: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta <$ min$\{1, \epsilon/3\}$. Then if $|x-2| < \delta$, we have $|x-2| < \delta < 1$, so $|x-4| = |x-2 + (-2)| \leq |x-2| + |-2| < 3$, so $|x^2-6x+8| < 3\delta < \epsilon$. Therefore $\lim_{x \to 2}(x^2 - 6x) = -8.$

Comment: How would you know that $\delta < min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$ without analyzing the limit?

Comment: To get a guess of what $\delta$ should be, you do the analysis that you did above. My point is that in your proof you must show that your guess of $\delta$ satisfies the required condition. You are trying to show that such a value of $\delta$ exists. That's why the first sentence in your proof, "Let $|x-2| < \delta$" doesn't make sense -- you didn't say what $\delta$ is.

Comment: How about setting it up like this to begin with:

Given a $\epsilon > 0$, we want to show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

And then continue like I did in my post.

Comment: That's a good start. Your next step would be to say "Let $\delta be a number less than 1 and \epsilon/3$," and then to show that such a value works.

Comment: That seems senseless. Wouldn't the next step be the analysis I did in the OP, thus concluding that $\delta = min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$?

Comment: No. Look at what you need to show. I'll quote you above: Given a ϵ>0, we want to show that there exists a δ>0 such that |x−a|<δ→|f(x)−L|<ϵ. Notice the phrase, "we want to show that there exists a δ>0." The question isn't what is $\delta$; the question is, does such a $\delta$ exist? If you continue the proof as you suggested then you're assuming that $\delta$ exists, so you're assuming exactly what you want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon > 0$

$|x^2 - 6x + 8| = |x-2||x-4|$

Now you want a bound for $|x-4|$, so you take $|x-2|<1$

$\therefore |x-4|= |x-2-4+2| \le |x-2|+|-2| < 1 + 2 < 3$

(using triangle inequality $|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$)

$\implies |x-2||x-4|<3|x-2|< \epsilon$

$\therefore |x-2|< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Take $\delta = min \lbrace 1, \frac{\epsilon}{3} \rbrace$ and you are done.